# Is it true that time dilation in a universe with no gravity could not be calculated without knowing how much mass is present in the universe?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, time, time-dilation

Looking for a quick clarification on something. I am a layman and I have been trying to find out how much time dilation would exist if there was no gravity anywhere, and ignoring what seem to be debates about whether a universe without matter is even a valid hypothetical, it seems the issue is time dilation is a product of gravitational potential, and as the amount of existing gravitational potential in the universe cannot currently be measured, the question cannot be answered, only comparisons between the GP of Earth and other locations could be made. Is this true?

If not, could someone highlight the time dilation in gravity-less space? I.e one second on earth vs in this hypothetical space that is a perfect vacuum with no effects of gravity? Most of the questions I have seen about this have been unanswered or given the various flaws of their specific asking of the question, which lead to me making this clarification post.

Comment: No, it is not true. It sounds like something you may have seen on YouTube, though. Let me guess... did this come from one of the infamous "physics content creators"?

Comment: Nope, just confusion from trying to figure out the answer to the question in the second paragraph but every question I see on the topic never has an answer rather just a bunch of people explaining various issues with the question, and I'm trying to pinpoint what the ultimate issue is, but it's usually very convoluted, at least to a layman. I haven't seen a direct answer to the question nor a direct explanation of the main issue with the question, mainly specific issues with how the question was asked etc. @FlatterMann

Comment: There is no issue. Time dilation drops out of a few dozen lines of algebra once you assume that the universe is metric, (locally) homogeneous, isotropic and that all physics is relative.  Unless you can find observational evidence that these assumptions are violated, then it's just a matter of knowing the right algebraic tricks to deduce the time dilation formula from first principles.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding *"time dilation in a universe with no gravity"* – a strong argument could be made that time dilation *is* gravity (objects "fall" or "curve" along the gradient of slower time).  So this hypothesis cannot really exist.  But in a perfectly flat spacetime with no matter or energy, relativistic time dilation due to different observer speed would still exist.  And if an observer accelerated, he would create an effective gravitational field that is only visible to him, but would cause the same time dilation effects as a gravitational field would.

Time dilation can be seen a consequence of the fact that the magnitude of the 4-velocity **V** of any object is always a constant, $c$ the speed of light.

$$\bf{V}=\gamma \begin{bmatrix} c \\ v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

In the object's own frame, $v_1=v_2=v_3=0$, and the direction of the velocity is purely in the time direction.  In another frame, where the object's velocities are non-zero, the direction of the 4-velocity "tilts" so that the time component is slower and the space components are faster.  This is exactly the same as when you take a vector in the X-Y plane that points along the X-axis and has length $L$, with components $\Delta X = L,\, \Delta Y = 0$.  If you rotate it 45°, the length is still $L$, but the components are $\Delta X = 0.71L, \Delta Y = 0.71L$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of time dilation, and [one kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Time_dilation_caused_by_a_relative_velocity) can definitely happen in a universe with no gravity. It just requires a fast speed.

I am not sure what kind of answer you are looking for, but note from the link that the theory used is special relativity, and special relativity assumes no mass. (If there is mass, then we need general relativity.)